# SharePoint search not shows all result

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

When search for particular keyword, its return only few not all results. So i tried to search 'everything' option then it throw access denied exception. How to fix this and how to get return all result in 'This Site' search? thanks in advance